# The two strings as inputs. Check whether one string is a substring of another. Ignore the uppercase/lowercase differences

Tags: string

The two strings as inputs. Check whether one string is a substring of
another. Ignore the uppercase/lowercase differences.

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy question,

```
largerString = "This is the larger string not the smaller string"
smallerString = "Smaller String"

if largerString.lower().find(smallerString.lower()) != -1:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

You can take the largerString and the smallerString as inputs.
It basically converted them both into lower case and checks if
the lower string is contained within the largerString by trying
to find it, if it finds it then it is contained else it is not.